# How can I display all the array elements in the HTML list?

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to show all items in the list. But I don't know how to do it. So please help. The code is:

```
$items = array(
                    array(
                        "category" => "Flour",
                        "products" => array(
                            array(
                                "name" => "Pastry",
                                "cost" => 7.00
                            ),
                            array(
                                "name" => "Whole Wheat",
                                "cost" => 4.20
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this by iterating through the array in a loop, accumulating the new HTML into it's own array and then joining the HTML all together and inserting it into the DOM at the end:

Edit code :

Supposed you got this kind of array :

```
$shop = array( array("title"=>"rose", "price"=>1.25 , "number"=>15),
               array("title"=>"daisy", "price"=>0.75 , "number"=>25),
               array("title"=>"orchid", "price"=>1.15 , "number"=>7) 
             );
```

then do something like this, which should work well even when you add more columns to your table in the database later :

```
<?php if (count($shop) > 0): ?>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($shop))); ?></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<?php foreach ($shop as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

take the example and adapt it to your own array , that's really easy !

Comment: Yes, please. Please help code to display it in the order list.

Comment: @SopheakITplus could you be more specific please ? maybe try to make a new post with your actual code that i can see your problem .